# Meteor: deploying under windows

Tags: windows, deployment, meteor

Is anybody else experiencing problems while deploying your application using the windows version?

According to the program output everything went fine and it should be serving at the chosen URL, but the only response from the browser is "This site is down. Try again later."

I then tried to deploy the simplest application possible, but it isn't working either.

Anybody knows if it is a common problem under windows?

I do have the latest version installed, meteor 0.4.0 for windows (from http://win.meteor.com/), under windows 7.

Thanks!

EDIT: apparently it is a bug in the windows version: I deployed my site under ubuntu without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor 0.5.0 is out, in Meteor 0.4.2 I fixed this to work for Git Bash on Windows.

In Meteor 0.5.1 I'm planning to make this work in both Git Bash and CMD.